# How to get inline elements to expand to line-height

Tags: html, css, block

Let's consider this block element :

```
<div style="background-color: gray; line-height: 30px;">
    Some text and a <a style="background-color: yellow;">link<\a>
<\div>
```

Why is the yellow color not taking the full height of the line? How can I fix it?

Also, if I put an inline-block on this line, it is expanded to the full height of the line. Why in this case?

**EDIT**

After thinking more about it, I think I've answered some of my questions :

First, the width and height of an inline element is not affected by the line-height property, hence the size of the yellow region for the `<a>` element. Second, the reason why inline-block elements seems to expand to the line-height is because they inherit their parent's line-height property. Thus, when I write some text inside an inline-block element, this text has a line-height equals to its parent. The inline-block's height expands so that it gets all that is inside of it ( = line-height of the text). This can be verified by creating an inline-block with no text in it and a defined width. In this case, there won't be a yellow region at all, since an inline-block (like any block element) has a height of 0 when it is empty.

So, I guess the right way to get an inline element (such as `<a>`, `<span>`, etc.) to have its height equals to line-height is to change it into an inline-block element. Or would there be another way?

Since all this comes from my intuition, can someone give me some confirmation?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the display property to inline-block:

Style elements

```
<style>

#your_dive {
    background-color: gray;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#your_anchor {
    diskplay: inline-block;
    background-color: yellow;
}

</style>
```

HTML elements

```
<div id="your_dive">
    Some text and a <a id="your_anchor">link</a>
</div>
```